# add image to rect polygon in leaflet

Tags: leaflet

Here is the working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y6hkov73/1/)

what I need is to add image to rect polygon and also don't want it to repeat itself as when zooming in or out and want it to be fixed. any suggestions will be appreciated and if there is any other way to achieve so.
If it can be placed in geojson that will be great as I have to give some properties to each polygon. And create all the rect polygon dynamically.

code is below

```
var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        osmAttrib = '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
        osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {maxZoom: 18, attribution: osmAttrib});
var map = new L.Map('map', {layers: [osm], center: new L.LatLng(24, 121), zoom: 9});
var states = [{
"type": "Feature",
"properties": {"party": "Republican"},
"geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [[
        [-104.05, 48.99],
        [-96.58,  45.94],
        [-104.03, 45.94],
        [-104.05, 48.99]
    ]]
}
}, {
"type": "Feature",
"properties": {"party": "Democrat"},
"geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [[
        [-109.05, 41.00],
        [-102.03, 36.99],
        [-109.04, 36.99],
        [-109.05, 41.00]
    ]]
}
}];
var poly1 = [
[24, 121],
[24.5, 121],
[24.5, 121.9],
[24, 121.9]
];
L.polygon(poly1, {fill:'url(http://i.imgur.com/ktPFJKC.jpg)'}).addTo(map);
 L.geoJson(states, {
style: function(feature) {
    switch (feature.properties.party) {
        case 'Republican': return {color:'#ff0000'};
        case 'Democrat':   return {color: "#0000ff"};
    }
}
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing to do here is use an [ImageOverlay](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#imageoverlay), which is designed for precisely this case. You can use the coordinates of your polygon object to create both the image overlay and an invisible GeoJSON layer that sits on top of it. If you are dynamically creating the polygon objects in the same format as your example `poly1`, then you can reference the indices of the corner points like this when creating the image overlay:

```
var imageUrl = 'http://i.imgur.com/ktPFJKC.jpg';
var imageBounds = L.latLngBounds([
    poly1[0],
    poly1[2]
  ]);

var imageLayer = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map).bringToBack();
```

The `.bringToBack` may be unnecessary if you always create the image before the GeoJSON polygon, but it does ensure that the image overlay doesn't interfere with other layer interactions. You can create a temporary GeoJSON object from the polygon object using `.toGeoJSON`, and set any GeoJSON properties you like:

```
var polyTemp = L.polygon(poly1).toGeoJSON();
polyTemp.properties.name = 'pineapple';
```

Then create an invisible `L.GeoJSON` layer to handle the interactions:

```
var boxOptions = {fillOpacity:0, opacity:0, onEachFeature: onEachBox};
var imageBox = L.geoJson(polyTemp, boxOptions).addTo(map);

function onEachBox(feature, layer) {
  layer.bindPopup("Hello, I'm a " + polyTemp.properties.name);
}
```

The `onEachBox` function here is of course just an example to illustrate that you can access the GeoJSON properties. Here is an updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/17Ld98fv/

Comment: There are a couple simple errors (am I correct in assuming [this is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/17Ld98fv/1/)?). First, you need to define your `poly1` and `poly2` objects *before* creating your `geojson`. Second is a problem of coordinates. While Leaflet expects points to be specified as [lat, lon], GeoJSON needs them to be [lon, lat]. You will see that if you set the opacity of the `L.geoJson` to 1, the boxes appear in the Indian Ocean, while one image overlay appears over Greenland and the other is missing (latitudes above 90 being invalid). http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/17Ld98fv/2/

Comment: So how can I correct this as there will be approx 40 elements and img url should only be taken from geojson as for now it is taking from variable you have defined.

Comment: I should point out that you can actually create the bounding box for the image overlay from the geojson very easily. Add this to the `onEachBox` function: `L.imageOverlay(feature.properties.url,layer.getBounds()).addTo(map).bringToBack();` and everything should work fine. See: http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/17Ld98fv/4/