# How can i an add image overlay depending on the options in the polygon properties in a leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a multi-polygon geojson file ( mapInfo ) that has one of the properties named "field_hazards". The hazards include "gale/storm, heavy rain, thunderstorm and Freezing rain "
How can i an add image overlay depending on the field_hazard options?

Note the geojson file is got dynamically as a drupal feed. I have made the following code but it returns an empty map, the polygons are not rendered.

```
 function getImage(d) {
 return d === 'Freezing Rain' ? "http://mymap:8082/images/weather-images/43n.png" :
        d === 'Thunderstorm' ? "http://mymap:8082/images/weather-images/11.png" :
        d === 'Heavy Rain' ? "http://my:8082/weather-images/02n.png" :
        d === 'Gale\/Storm' ? "http://mymap:8082/images/weather-images/15.png" :
                        "http://my:8082/images/weather-images/09.png";

}
var imageUrl = getImage(feature.properties.field_hazards);
var imageLayer = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map).bringToBack();
var boxOptions = {fillOpacity:0, opacity:0, onEachFeature: onEachBox};
//create the image interaction box
var imageBox = L.geoJson(mapInfo, boxOptions).addTo(map);
//zoom in to fit GeoJSON layer
map.fitBounds(imageBox.getBounds());
```

I have looked at this example " [add image to rect polygon in leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35707740/add-image-to-rect-polygon-in-leaflet)
 ", but it requires me to have the image url preset as a property its self.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution from this link. Posted it in case some else is interested.

[Adding image overly in leaflet map from a property](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188496/how-can-i-an-add-image-overlay-depending-on-the-options-in-the-polygon-propertie/188541#188541)